# How to fix samba share connection problems with secpol.msc?

Tags: windows-10, samba, ntlm-authentication

I had one client who could not connect to a samba share giving the error that the **credentials where wrong** while I was sure they where not.

This happened suddenly on a laptop with Windows 10 while other clients with Windows 10, Windows 7 and Ubuntu etc. all where able to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first I was suspecting the problem beeing a change in the hash or key for the share - and maybe it really was because Putty was saying so when I tried to SSH into the server.

But I could not find any saved connection to delete with `net use`.

The solution was to change a setting in `secpol.msc` which is accessible as administrator via the search even in Windows 10 Home.

I had to set LAN-Manager-Authenticationlevel to **just send NTLMv2**.

You will find this setting under Security settings -> local -> Security options -> Network Security: LAN-Manager-Authenticationlevel.

(I translated this from German. Feel free to edit with nativ english wording.)